# From second quantisation Hamiltonian to general Hamiltonian form of Rice-Mele Model

Tags: condensed-matter, second-quantization, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I am concerning the following second quantization Hamiltonian: 
\begin{equation}
H=\sum_j(\frac{t}{2}+(-1)^j\frac{\delta}{2})(c^\dagger_jc_{j+1}+H.c.)+\delta(-1)^jc_j^\dagger c_j
\end{equation}
describing one dimensional dimerized lattice model, from the review article on Berry phase arxiv.org/abs/0907.2021 Page.12. Then how can it be written in the form as:
\begin{equation}
H(q)=\vec{h}(q)\cdot\vec{\sigma}; \vec{h}(q)=(t\cos\frac{qa}{2},-\delta\sin\frac{qa}{2},\Delta)
\end{equation}
where $\vec{\sigma}$ is the Pauli matrices. In the Hamiltonian each $i$ corresponds to a lattice index, and each lattice have two-energy-level structure.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2021

Comment: Use the Bloch representation
$$c_{j}=\sum_{q\in{B.Z}}c_{q}e^{-iqa_{j}}$$